# Cmder/Conemu: dynamically name tab title from within task definition

Tags: conemu, cmder

I am using Putty in Cmder to ssh to a 'jumpbox'.  I then pass a hostname in a file using the -m ssh option to jump to the 'real' destination host.

I want to dynamically set the title of the putty tab from within a task definition in Cmder/ConEmu to be the hostname I'm jumping to. In the screenshot below you can see that I have attempted to use "%REMOTE_HOST%" to pass in an environment variable containing the title that I want to have on my tab.  However this just creates a tab named %REMOTE_HOST%.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Answer: `HOST` is not defined in your environment variables.

Comment: @Maximus, have now renamed HOST to REMOTE_HOST to clarify why I need to set dynamically.  But at the time I had this running, HOST and now REMOTE_HOST are indeed valid environment variables.  It just seems ConEmu does not evaluate them when used with the -new_console:t flag.

Comment: Of course -new_console:t has effect *only* during console startup.

Comment: But does it evaluate the env variable on console startup?  Doesn't seem to.  e.g. try putting -new_console:t:"%PATH%".  The tab name will be the literal "%PATH%", it's not evaluated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I explained many times that PuTTY and mintty are not console applications, they are [GUI applications](https://conemu.github.io/en/ChildGui.html) with their own graphical interface.

An analogy: you run VirtualBox with Ubuntu (as client) in Windows (as host) and some console application in you VirtualBox-ed Ubuntu. Don't you wonder why TaskBar in Windows does not show the title of Ubuntu console?

When you run [ChildGUI](https://conemu.github.io/en/ChildGui.html) in ConEmu it shows in the Tab children window title.

#### What you need to do

Configure PuTTY or your remote host (e.g. bash prompt with [ANSI](https://conemu.github.io/en/AnsiEscapeCodes.html#OSC_Operating_system_commands)) to show proper text in PuTTY title. The questsion has nothing to do with ConEmu.

Also, ensure that the tab bar console template in ConEmu/Cmder settings is or contains %s.  e.g.

[image]

Comment: Oddly enough, the remote hosts _are_ setting the title using ansi.  e.g. "\033]0;"myhost"\007".  But the title in Cmder still shows as 'Putty".  However..... when I click on 'Rename tab' the hostname appears in the edit box, and without changing anything if I click OK, the tab title changes from "Putty" to the true hostname.  Just like what I'm after!

Comment: 1. On screenshots there's old ConEmu build. 2. You may be renamed tab with -new_console:t? 3. Depends on your configured tab template.

Comment: 1. Yes sorry, it is an old build.  It's whatever comes with the Cmder download.  The company I work for, in it's wisdom, has blocked github.io.  2. I tried removing the -new_console:t rename, but still same behaviour.  3. Sorry, what do you mean by tab template?

Comment: So, you can't access docs site? https://conemu.github.io/en/InternetIssues.html#auto-location and https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsTabBar.html#id2106